# Which file system is better to be used on an external HDD? ExFAT or NTFS?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, exfat

I have an older 500 GB external HDD which I want to format. Which FS is better if the HDD won't be used with anything else than Windows 10?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/235596/whats-the-difference-between-fat32-exfat-and-ntfs/

Comment: It's a question of security. exFAT is now pretty-well universally functional, so is more adaptable to alternative devices like printers, scanners and macOS. However, NTFS, while less pervasive, offers role- and user-based security so you could limit access to the content from other users of the device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually no big difference between ExFat or NTFS, the only thing to must know, for which OS you are going to use, for mac or for Win or for both. In case if you are going to use Mac or both Mac and Win you need ExFat because of Mac by default doesn't support NTFS. Otherwise, there is no difference.